# combine @RepositoryRestResource and @RestResource in spring repository

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa

I have the following repository exposed as restful endpoint following hypermedia-based RESTful spring techno.
here is the tutorial followed to create such repository [accessing-data-rest-tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/)

```
    @RepositoryRestResource(path = "tuple", collectionResourceRel = "tuple")
    public interface TupleRepository extends JpaRepository<Tuple, Integer> {

        @RestResource(path = "findAllByAnr", rel = "findAllByAnr")
        List<Tuple> findAllByAnr(@Param("anr") String anr);

}
```

I am able to call the standard  hypermedia-based RESTful  like

```
http://localhost:8081/tuple/1
http://localhost:8081/shared-dao/tuple?page=5
```

Question :
1 - what is the endpoint url of the findAllByAnr method that i just have exposed ?
2- is there any documentation for these 2 annotation when combined together

```
@RepositoryRestResource
@RepositoryRestResource
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It should be available on:  `http://localhost:8081/tuple/search/findAllByAnr?anr=somevalue`
2. This should be helpful: [SDR docs - configuring url](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.configuring-the-rest-url-path)